# Cómo pasar un input str a int. Cómo ordenar de menor a mayor lista de int

Tags: python-3.x

Buenas tardes a tod@s,

Me he estado rebanando el seso para resolver este ejercicio, pero a lo máximo que he llegado es a una diarrea programadora curiosa, cosas de principiantes supongo.

No me gusta tener que pedir ayuda para resolver un ejercicio entero, pero de verdad que no logro averiguar como hacerlo; las malditas comas me trastocan cualquier idea.

Muchas gracias a todos

```
entry = input('Enteros separados por comas: ') 

transform_entry = entry.replace(',','') # Para no lea las comas 


new_transform_entry = transform_entry.replace(' ','') # elimino espacios

int_entry = int(new_transform_entry) # str input a int

list = [int_entry]

print(list)
```

El ejercicio es el que aparece en la captura:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mis conocimientos han llegado para resolver esto:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Cuál es realmente el problema? ¿Que no pasa los tests? Muestra todo lo que has intentado, y dale un título _descriptivo_ a tu pregunta. Lee [ask].

Comment: @padaleina yo creo que está bastante claro. A mi pasarlo o no me da igual, quiero aprender cómo hacerlo. He intentado más soluciones pero igual de infructuosas, por ende considero irrelevante ponerlas.

Comment: Bienvenidx. Recuerda que las preguntas acá quedan para que en el futuro otros puedan resolver sus dudas también. Entender que sus aproximaciones son las mismas que las tuyas y que también te fallan, va a ayudar a otros a validar su propia pregunta y saber si la respuesta aceptada les sirve o no. Lo otro, es posible que tus soluciones tengan problemas menores, fáciles de resolver. Siempre será mucho más fácil el ajuste mínimo que una solución completa.

Comment: Y lo último: el plan no es llegar con un "no supe"; siempre es más productivo llegar con un [Ejemplo mínimo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Como te han comentado, la pregunta y sus respuestas deben ser útiles no solo para vos, sino para los demás miembros de la comunidad. Es por ello que debés especificar cuál es la pregunta en cuestión.

Comment: @Alfabravo creo que entiendo lo que me queréis decir. Tengo que formular una pregunta general para poder ayudar a quien tenga el mismo problema con diferente enunciado.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El ejercicio tiene por finalidad practicar los aspectos básicos de manejo de listas.

```
entry = input('Enteros separados por comas: ') => "4,6,1,3,9,7"
```

Con `split()` transformamos el string en una lista de string, cada uno representando un entero, produciendo

```
['4', '6', '1', '3', '9', '7']
```

Con una comprensión de listas recorremos esa lista tomando cada string y transformandolo a un entero:

```
resultado = [int(x) for x in entry.split(",")] => [4, 6, 1, 3, 9, 7]
```

Esa lista la ordenamos *in situ*

```
resultado.sort() => [1, 3, 4, 6, 7, 9]
```

Pero ahi queda ordenada de menor a mayor, y la quieres al revés. Lo más simple es una rebanada de lista con paso negativo, que la da vuelta:

```
ordenado = resultado[::-1] => [9, 7, 6, 4, 3, 1]
```

Y listo

#### Demo

```
entry = input('Enteros separados por comas: ')
resultado = [int(x) for x in entry.split(",")]
resultado.sort()
ordenado = resultado[::-1]
print(ordenado)
```

produce:

```
Enteros separados por comas: 4,6,1,3,9,7
[9, 7, 6, 4, 3, 1]

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: Muchísimas gracias de nuevo, funciona a la perfección. Es increíble cómo lo haces parecer tan fácil y elegante! La solución [int(x) for x in entry.split(",")] me parece una genialidad.

Comment: Si quieres la lista de mayor a menor, no necesitas slices. Alcanza con poner el argumento reverse=True a resultado.sort

Comment: @DanteS. Cómo dice la respuesta, "manejo básico de manejo de listas". Rebanadas vas a ocupar a cada paso; sort ... no tanto.

Answer (score -1):

```
entry = input('Enteros separados por comas: ')
entry.sort(reverse = True) 

transform_entry = entry.replace(',','') # Para no lea las comas 


new_transform_entry = transform_entry.replace(' ','') # elimino espacios

int_entry = int(new_transform_entry) # str input a int

list = [int_entry]

print(list)
```

probá con ese codigo, segun recuerdo e investigue la funcion sort() ordena los valores en las listas de forma descendente ya sean numeros o letras

Comment: `entry` es un string, por lo que `entry.sort()` falla. ¿Podrías ejecutar tu código y verificar los resultados?